# Use Two hibernate.cfg.xml files in a Application

Tags: java, hibernate

how to specify two hibernate configurations for a one application,
i have created two hibernate files and mention them in SessionFactory.util

hibernateMaster.cfg.xml file is working fine..
but when shut down Master database server and try to use application with hibernateMaster.cfg.xml and retrieve data it gives me "null"

but if i restart the Application it is working fine with hibernateMaster.cfg.xml file

here are my hibernate files

hibernateMaster.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database Connection Settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.232.143:3306/cps</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">gaiz</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mysql</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/Patient.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/Allergy.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/Hospital.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/StatStaff.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/StatWard.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/UserRole.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/UserLog.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernateSlave.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database Connection Settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.232.144:3306/cps</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">gaiz2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mysql</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>


        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/Patient.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/Allergy.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/Hospital.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/StatStaff.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/StatWard.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/User.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/UserRole.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="lib/driver/mappings/UserLog.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

SessionFactoryUtil.java

```
package lib;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import core.resources.statisticalResource;

public class SessionFactoryUtil {
    //This class creates a session factory object by looking at the hibernate configuration (hibernate.cfg.xml)

    private static SessionFactory sesFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry sesRegistry;
    static Configuration cfg;
    static{
        try{
             cfg= new Configuration().configure("lib/hibernateMaster.cfg.xml");
            sesRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            sesFactory=cfg.buildSessionFactory(sesRegistry);
            try{

                Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
                System.out.println("Connected to Master Database Server");
            }                   
            catch(Throwable ex){
                cfg= new Configuration().configure("lib/hibernateSlave.cfg.xml"); 
                sesRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
                sesFactory=cfg.buildSessionFactory(sesRegistry);
                System.out.println("Connected to Slave Database Server");
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable ex){
            System.out.println("Master & Slave Database Error.");
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory Creation Failed"+ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }   
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sesFactory;
    }
}
```

i dnt knw whether i have done something wrong on have done something wrong in SessionFactoryUtil.java .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you initialize your factory in a static way.

```
static{
  ...
}
```

That code is executed only once, when you start your application. That way when you shut down your master server hibernate stills asking for it.

You should initialize both configurations and use the main, if exists, or secondary in other case. You can do this in the getSessionFactory() method, that is executed each time the method is call, but not in an static initializer.